# Multiple Background in single view Issues

Tags: ios

I have two types of background (1 image and 1 video player)

parentView -> (**BackgroundImageview** and **BackgroundVideoView**)

There is one another view in which I have to show some part with BackagroundImageview and another part contains BackgroundVideoView.

[image]
[image]

like given image white part  comes with  BackgroundVideoView and the gray line comes with  BackgroundImageview.

Dummy Source Code - [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftAmit/DemoBackgroundProblem)

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is your problem and question.

Comment: @LGP there is two background view i have to show both backgroundview in same View which are split

Comment: Can you just put them on top of each other with transparency on the top one?

Comment: @LGP i need both background on same level of view we can set one top at a time

Comment: Well, one of them must be on top of the other. I don't understand the problem, to be honest. Why wouldn't it work to put two `UIImageView` on top of each other, and use transparency to let the bottom one through.